# Android : CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1

Tags: java, android, mobile, mobile-application

I have an error it says

```
Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1
```

I don't know what causes the error, the error is on the line `cursor.getString(17));` need help

```
Cursor cursor_other_card = MainActivity.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT ocv.id,ocv.card_holder_name,ocv.card_number_system_generated,ocv.card_number_inputted,ocv.card_number_series,ocv.distribution_status,ocv.release_date,ocv.release_by,ocv.release_place,ocv.card_physically_presented,ocv.card_pin_is_attached,ocv.reason_not_presented,ocv.reason_unclaimed,ocv.card_replacement_requests,ocv.card_replacement_request_submitted_details,ocv.pawning_remarks,ocv.other_image, ocv.others_reason_not_presented,ocv.others_reason_unclaimed FROM other_card_validations AS ocv LEFT JOIN emv_validation_details AS evd ON evd.id = ocv.emv_validation_detail_id WHERE evd.id="+id);
    Integer i =0;
    while (cursor_other_card.moveToNext()) {
        i++;
        //5 other_card_validations
        myEdit.putString("card_holder_name"+i+"_u",cursor_other_card.getString(1));
        myEdit.putString("card_number_system_generated"+i+"_u",cursor_other_card.getString(2));
        myEdit.putString("card_number_inputted"+i+"_u",cursor_other_card.getString(3));
        myEdit.putString("card_number_series"+i+"_u",cursor_other_card.getString(4));
        myEdit.putString("distribution_status"+i+"_u",cursor_other_card.getString(5));
        myEdit.putString("release_date"+i+"_u",cursor_other_card.getString(6));
        myEdit.putString("release_by"+i+"_u",cursor_other_card.getString(7));
        myEdit.putString("release_place"+i+"_u",cursor_other_card.getString(8));
        myEdit.putString("card_physically_presented"+i+"_u",cursor_other_card.getString(9));
        myEdit.putString("card_pin_is_attached"+i+"_u",cursor_other_card.getString(10));
        myEdit.putString("reason_not_presented"+i+"_u",cursor_other_card.getString(11));
        myEdit.putString("reason_unclaimed"+i+"_u",cursor_other_card.getString(12));
        myEdit.putString("card_replacement_request"+i+"_u",cursor_other_card.getString(13));
        myEdit.putString("card_replacement_request_submitted_details"+i+"_u",cursor_other_card.getString(14));
        myEdit.putString("pawning_remarks"+i+"_u",cursor_other_card.getString(15));
        if (cursor_other_card.getBlob(16) != null) {
            if (i == 1) {
                ocv_other_image_1_u = cursor_other_card.getBlob(16);
            } else if (i == 2) {
                ocv_other_image_2_u = cursor_other_card.getBlob(16);
            } else if (i == 3) {
                ocv_other_image_3_u = cursor_other_card.getBlob(16);
            } else if (i == 4) {
                ocv_other_image_4_u = cursor_other_card.getBlob(16);
            } else if (i == 5) {
                ocv_other_image_5_u = cursor_other_card.getBlob(16);
            }
        }
        myEdit.putString("others_reason_not_presented"+i+"_u", cursor.getString(17)); //the error goes here
        myEdit.putString("others_reason_unclaimed"+i+"_u", cursor.getString(18));
    }
    cursor_other_card.close();
```

Comment: Can not see any thing in your code about `cursor` - are you sure that this variable is not `cursor_other_card`?

Comment: @Scary Wombat Thanks I forgot to update

Comment: Maybe better to delete this question then?

Answer (score 0):

You have an off by 1 error.

```
Integer i =0;
while (cursor_other_card.moveToNext()) {
    i++;
    //5 other_card_validations
    myEdit.putString("card_holder_name"+i+"_u",cursor_other_card.getString(1));
```

For an array of N, this code would make I go 1 to N, instead of 0 to N-1.  To fix this, increment i at the end of the loop, not the beginning.

Also, you should make it int i=0, not Integer.  No reason to use the class when a primitive is available.